# AccessViolationException error

Tags: c#, opencv, access-violation

I want to ask you a question.When I tired to use Marshal.ReadByte, I get an error that "Attempt to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."I made a search but I still can't solve this problem.Can you  help me please? Here is my code.

```
unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 IplImage I_input = Cv.LoadImage("1.6.tif", LoadMode.GrayScale);

  IntPtr ptr2 = I_input.ImageData;

            for (int x = 0; x < I_input.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < I_input.Height; y++)
                {
                    int offset = (I_input.WidthStep * y) + (x * 3);
                    byte b = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr2, offset + 0);    // B
                    byte g = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr2, offset + 1);    // G
                    byte r = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr2, offset + 2);    // R
                    Marshal.WriteByte(ptr2, offset, r);
                    Marshal.WriteByte(ptr2, offset, g);
                    Marshal.WriteByte(ptr2, offset, b);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error? are the values in the parameters sensible? is ptr2 not IntPtr.Zero?

Comment: I get the error at this line; byte b = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr2, offset + 0);

Comment: Ok, so the first ReadByte. Now, can you answer the RELEVANT part of the question? What is the value of offset and what is the value of ptr2?

Comment: Is your assumption of 3 bytes per pixel correct? seeing as you are forcing `GrayScale` (note: i have never used or know the library you are using)

Comment: What is the `depth` value of `I_input`? Since you load the image as Greyscale I would assume it's not RGB as you try to read it. You also ignore `widthStep` value which might get you into further troubles...

Comment: ptr2= 156368944 and the first offset valuse=0

Comment: I change the fisrt line;
  IplImage I_input = Cv.LoadImage("1.6.tif");like this.
I think the problem solved.You right.I read my image grayscale but ı tried to read byte rgb scale.